# Joomla Extension to List Courses

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I need to present to the front end of my page a list of available courses , for students to take, I use a quizz sytem called jquarks , but it laks the ability to show courses listing. Can someone tell me what is avialble in joomla that I can use to make the courses ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend either [amoCourse](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/living/education-a-culture/courses/7644) or [Course Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/living/education-a-culture/courses/8141).

According to the Joomla Extensions Directory is amoCourse a free component whereas Course Manager is a commercial component.

Both are available for Joomla 1.5, only Course Manager is also compatible with new Joomla versions (1.6+).